# Add multiple lines to a plot_ly graph with add_trace

Tags: r, plotly

I found an example to add lines to a `plot_ly` plot by using the `add_trace` command. How can I add a list of lines to plot without using `add_trace` multiple times?

I tried a `for` loop to add the traces but this doesn't work as expected.

```
my_lines <- list(
  list(x=1:10, y=2:11, color='red'),
  list(x=1:10, y=0:9, color='blue'),
  list(x=1:10, y=3:12, color='green')
)
p <- plot_ly()
p
for(line in my_lines) {  p <- add_trace(p, y=line[['y']], x=line[['x']], 
                 marker=list(color=line[['color']]))
}
p
```

But this for example works as expected.

```
p <- plot_ly()
p <- add_trace(p, y=my_lines[[1]][['y']], x=my_lines[[1]][['x']],
               marker=list(color=my_lines[[1]][['color']]))
p <- add_trace(p, y=my_lines[[2]][['y']], x=my_lines[[2]][['x']],
               marker=list(color=my_lines[[2]][['color']]))
p <- add_trace(p, y=my_lines[[3]][['y']], x=my_lines[[3]][['x']],
               marker=list(color=my_lines[[3]][['color']]))
p
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `evaluate = TRUE` to force evalutation / avoid lazy evaluation

```
p <- plot_ly()
p
for(line in my_lines) {  p <- add_trace(p, y=line[['y']], x=line[['x']], 
                 marker=list(color=line[['color']]),
                 evaluate = TRUE)
}
p
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Is there in general a better way of plotting multiple lines? I am aware of using a `data.frame`, but I have several lines with strange colours and extra hover names etc, so it might be easier to create a list instead of a long data frame.

Comment: @drmariod using a list seems fine to me, but I'm not sure what concerns you have with using a list.  I guess, I'm asking what you mean by "a better way."

Answer (score 10):

I believe with the release of `plotly 4.0` calling any of the `add_*` family of functions forces evaluation so there is no need to call `evaluate = T` anymore

So, something like this should work fine:

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly()

for(i in 1:5){
  p <- add_trace(p, x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10), mode = "lines")
}

p
```

[image]

Comment: It's also mandatory to start with an empty plot_ly(). If you define the first line in the plot_ly() function, then it doesn't work.

Comment: The solution above causes another problem though: the super annoying plotly auto sorting of the data on the X axis. Would you know how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can transform your inputs into a long-form data frame first, then plot using the `split` argument.

```
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)

my_lines = data.frame(x = 1:10, red = 2:11, blue = 0:9, green = 3:12)
my_lines_long = reshape2::melt(my_lines, id.vars = "x")
fig = plotly::plot_ly(my_lines_long, x = ~x, y = ~value, split = ~variable,
                      marker=list(color=~variable))
fig
```