# Plotly add_trace using lapply or for loops doesnt work

Tags: r, plotly

How can I add_trace in a loop when using  a list of dataframes

I keep getting the following using code below

```
df1<-c(seq(1:32))
df2<-df*2
df3<-df2*8
dff1<-sqrt(df1)
dff2<-sqrt(df2)
dff3<-sqrt(df3)


a<-cbind.data.frame(df1,dff1)
b<-cbind.data.frame(df2,dff2)
c<-cbind.data.frame(df3,dff3)
colnames(a)<-c("df1","df2")
colnames(b)<-c("df1","df2")
colnames(c)<-c("df1","df2")

df<-list()
df[[1]]<-a
df[[2]]<-b
df[[3]]<-c

pl<-plot_ly()
for(i in 1:3){

  pl<- add_trace(pl,data=df[[i]],x=~df[[i]]$df1,y=~df[[i]]$df2,mode='lines',type='scatter') 


}

pl
```

[image]

and when using lapply instead of for loops i get three seperate graphs instead of one graph with three lines

```
pl<-plot_ly()

pl<-lapply(1:3, function(i){

  pl<- pl%>%
    add_trace(data=df[[i]],x=~df[[i]]$df1,y=~df[[i]]$df2,mode='lines',type='scatter',inherit = TRUE) 


})
pl
```

Comment: Use `evaluate = TRUE` in `add_trace`.

Comment: I knew about evaluate = TRUE in add_trace  from other posts. But that doesn't work

Comment: I think your problem is in using dollar sign notation for `x` and `y` instead of referring directly to the variable.  Use `data=df[[i]],x=~df1,y=~df2` instead.  Since *plotly 4.0* evaluation is forced so `evaluation = TRUE` is [no longer needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38830530/2461552)

Comment: That worked for for loops. I did the same change using lapply that still produces three separate graphs. Is there a way to get lapply to add_trace in loop like fashion instead of it creating three separate charts

Comment: The three separate graphs has to do with how the `apply` family works.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2657002/2461552) for how to alter things outside the scope of the function via `assign` or `<<-`, although sticking with the loop for this task is an easy alternative.

Answer (score 1):

While other users have correctly noted that this can simply be done with a for loop, I figured I might as well just answer how to do it with lapply() for any future folks who come upon this question.

This can be done with lapply() by using the get() method, which allows you to specify the environment when retrieving a variable. Wrapping your lapply with invisible() prevents the loop from printing intermediates to you console/viewer as it runs.

Here is the code:

```
df1<-c(seq(1:32))
df2<-df1*2
df3<-df2*8
dff1<-sqrt(df1)
dff2<-sqrt(df2)
dff3<-sqrt(df3)


a<-cbind.data.frame(df1,dff1)
b<-cbind.data.frame(df2,dff2)
c<-cbind.data.frame(df3,dff3)
colnames(a)<-c("df1","df2")
colnames(b)<-c("df1","df2")
colnames(c)<-c("df1","df2")

df<-list()
df[[1]]<-a
df[[2]]<-b
df[[3]]<-c

pl<-plot_ly()

invisible(lapply(seq_along(df), FUN = function(i) {
  pl <<- get("pl", envir = globalenv()) %>% 
    add_trace(pl,data=df[[i]],x=~df[[i]]$df1,y=~df[[i]]$df2,mode='lines',type='scatter')  
}))

pl
```